# Apply LIMIT And OFFSET Clauses In A MySQL Query To A Specific Table, When The Query Selects Data From Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the early stages of setting some functionality to control pagination of some image board components with PHP/MySQL.

What I need to do initially is set the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses only on the `boards` table part of the query. This is so I can paginate by boards displayed.

The images that appear on the boards (4 preview images per board) are controlled by a counter inside a `while` loop when this data is outputted, so it is important that LIMIT or OFFSET are not applied to those.

The data is fetched with one query to prevent doing nested MySQL calls to the database which would be a performance problem.

There are 3 tables at play in the MySQL below - a `boards` table, an `images` table, and a `boards_images` table that is a pivot/linking table with a many-to-many relationship that stores the images that are allocated to the boards.

**Question**

In the following code, how would I set it so the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses only apply to the `boards` table. I can't work out if I need to group the data, or do a subquery, neither of which I have done before, or if the solution is neither of those approaches?

**Initial Query**

```
    $s = "SELECT boards.board_name, boards.board_id, boards.user_id, images.filename, images.image_title
    FROM boards
    LEFT JOIN boards_images ON boards_images.board_id = boards.board_id
    LEFT JOIN images        ON boards_images.image_id = images.image_id
    WHERE boards.user_id = :user_id
    ORDER BY boards.board_id DESC
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20 // only apply this to the boards table
    ";

// then add the $queryString variable to a PHP PDO prepare() method etc
```

**Attempting It With A Subquery**

In relation to Rick James answer, I think this is more what I need to be aiming for, it still isn't working though and throws and error on the first table to be queried in the first `SELECT` clause.

Within this I have set up a subquery, which contains the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

```
SELECT b.board_name, b.board_id, b.user_id, i.filename, i.image_title
FROM (
    SELECT board_name, board_id, user_id
    FROM boards AS b
    WHERE b.user_id = :user_id
    ORDER BY b.board_id DESC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
) AS t
LEFT JOIN boards_images AS bi ON bi.board_id = t.board_id
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON bi.image_id = i.image_id
```

Comment: If you paginate your boards, it seems that you would only ever want to select from the joined tables for images matching boards. Why would you want to select everything from the other tables? Have you looked at the data you actually receive with the above query?

Comment: @MarkusAO A user's empty boards are shown as well. They can create an empty board and then add images to that board from the image library. Users will be limited to an as yet undecided number of boards so things don't get out of hand.

Comment: If you're saying that you want to _make all images available_ (in an image library) to _any boards_, then you should probably just make a separate query fetching data for your image library. A `JOIN` will merge the columns from the joined tables into rows, and any `LIMIT` you apply will apply to all those (composite) rows. You could conceivably craft a  `RIGHT JOIN` and apply a `WHERE` filter to limit what boards are selected. Perhaps not. Easier and cheaper to just make a separate simple query fetching the images.

Comment: @MarkusAO  I'm not saying that. The images are already allocated to boards in the `boards_images` table (via a separate process), which is a linking/pivot many-to-many table. That aspect is all taken care of. These are board previews for logged in users, that hold 4 images a specific related board. If you click on the preview it takes you to the full board so you can view all of the images for that board.

Comment: Then it is unclear to me why you would not want to limit the whole lot, if you only want to select images that relate to the boards being displayed.

Comment: @MarkusAO I've added a screenshot so you can see how they are outputted. I want to limit these to say 20 per page. If you click on 'board 1' it takes to all of the images on board 1. The boards themselves don't have an image limit yet, but they will do at some point. The board previews (shown) have a limit of 4 images per preview (controlled by a counter inside a loop).

Comment: @MarkusAO also I've only given these boards numeric names to make testing the limit/offset easier. They will obviously have user defined names in reality.

Comment: I'm still confused over where the 20 applies.  And what if board 2 had 44 images, would the output stop before board 3 gets a chance to show?  Is that only 3 images for board 1?

Comment: @PushkrajJori I've done that and now have a broader knowledge. None of the what I have seen solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to this, which was as follows:

```
SELECT b.board_name, b.board_id, b.user_id, i.filename, i.image_title
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, board_id, board_name
        FROM boards
        WHERE user_id = :user_id
        ORDER BY board_id DESC
        LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
    ) AS b
LEFT JOIN boards_images AS bi ON bi.board_id = b.board_id
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON bi.image_id = i.image_id
```

This only places the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` on the `boards` table as desired. The numeric values for `:limit` and `:offset` are obviously defined outside of the MySQL for security reasons

Comment: I quote, "The data is fetched with one query to prevent doing nested MySQL calls to the database which would be a performance problem."

Comment: @Nikkorian - nested as in inside the loop that outputs the boards, which is how I've seen other people approach this type of thing - by having a second individual database call happen for each looped item

Comment: Please specify the syntax errors you encountered in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT .. OFFSET .. ) AS t1
    JOIN ... ON ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

In some cases, I recommend this as an optimization for a slow query.  By limiting (via `LIMIT` or `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`) the number of rows in the 'derived' table (`t1`), the rest of the query runs faster.  Also it *may* be possible to make better use of a composite index in `t1`.

I may even suggest another optimization that uses the above technique.  `JOIN` back to the original table to pick up the bulky columns (eg `TEXTs`) rather than hauling them around for filtering out later (via `LIMIT`, etc).

`OFFSET` is a terrible way to do pagination.  In the simple formulations, the SQL gathers everything first, then sorts, then does offset+limit.  Or, if an `INDEX` can help with the `ORDER BY + LIMIT`, the query runs slower and slower as you page forward.  More on [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) .

The formulation above tries to isolate the pain of `OFFSET` in the subquery.  However, without seeing the entire query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I can't say how effective the technique is.

There is a possible problem is with the `JOIN`.  If each row in `t1` 'joins' to zero or more than one row in the other table(s), then the `LIMIT` cannot be used in the derived table -- it will grab too many or too few rows.  Again, I need to see the use case before saying whether *your* query has this problem.

`LEFT JOIN t2...` allows you to include missing rows from t2.  You get `NULL` for any of `t2.*`.  This *may* solve the "zero" case above.

`( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM pets ... ) AS pet_names` could be used to handle the "or more" case above.  That way, you have a commalist of the pet names in a single row.  It also handles the "zero" case.

```
SELECT  kids.child_name,
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM pets 
            WHERE kids.id = pets.owner_id ) AS pet_names
    FROM kids
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT ... OFFSET ...
```

Now you can further optimize things by getting rid of `OFFSET`!
Instead, "remember where you left off" in `kids` (based on the `ORDER BY`).  That is discussed further in my pagination link above.

Comment: Thanks Rick. In terms of the numbers, the absolute maximum number of boards a user can have will be probably be 500, so in terms of the large page numbers I'm not too concerned about that. That concept will be useful on another bit of the site though - the infinite scroll in the main image library which I have yet to do. I'm not sure I understand the first part of the answer though, in terms of how that relates to limiting the number from the boards table?

Comment: Tip:  look for "lazy loading" of the pictures.

Comment: Another tip:  indexes for `boards_images`:  [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: So, that's about 2000 images for the biggest user?  Can a board have more than 4 images?   What LIMIT do you anticipate using for number of boards?

Comment: yes a board can have a lot of images (as yet undecided total). When a user clicks on the previews (shown in the photo) it takes them to the boards page for that board. The images do already have lazy loading (HTML attribute and javascript backup). The boards page is going to have infinite scrolling (up to the yet-to-be decided total number of images for the board, but probably 500).

Comment: ... also, yes the `boards_images` columns are indexed (they are foreign keys of the IDs from the `boards` and `images` columns.

Comment: @paulo77 - foreign keys is not as effective as two 2-column indexes.

Comment: hi rick - I've added an attempted subquery based on the code at the top of your answer. It still isn't working but I think this is nearer to what needs to happen. Can you see what is going wrong in the additional code? Thanks

Comment: @paulo77 - That revision limits the output to 10 boards.  (However it talks about limiting to 2, so it is a bit confusing.)  It does not limit 4 images per board (but you say the client code takes care of that.)  If it is good, then I suggest `INDEX(user_id, board_id, board_name)`.

Comment: @paulo77 - Let's focus on the subquery by itself.  Run that by itself, show us the output, then explain why the output is "wrong".  Once we have that part working "correctly", the `LEFT JOINs` should work OK; if they don't then, again, show us the text output from the query.  If that looks good, but the web page is still not right, then it must be in the PHP code?

Comment: Whenever I try the subquery it always throws an error at the first column selected.  In the context of the subquery code I've put in the amended question this is: `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'b.board_name' in 'field list'` This column does exist though, and when I run a basic query (without the subquery) the aliases all work OK and the columns are selected

Comment: Change from "b." to "t.".  The outer `SELECT` cannot see what is going on inside the subquery; it can only see what is exported via the `SELECT` list.

Comment: @Rick James, didn't the OP specify no nested queries?

Comment: @Nikkorian - The OP implied that a subquery might be (1) a performance and (2) a learning issue; I am suggesting that it may _improve_ performance and I am helping in learning about subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The OP declares his question very clearly: "In the following code, how would I set it so the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses only apply to the boards table."  I am interested that Rick James' answer, and the discussion it provoked, focus on performance and the general question of pagination. Can someone tell me if this divergence is because the OP requested a Canonical answer?

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Here's a simple approach that delivers the required data, albeit in a different structure to the OP's spec. It just requires you to parse the images column values for the individual images in each board:

```
SELECT b.board_name,b.board_id, b.user_id, group_concat(concat(i.filename,"||", i.image_title) SEPARATOR ",") as images
FROM boards AS b
LEFT JOIN boards_images AS bi ON bi.board_id = b.board_id
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON bi.image_id = i.image_id
WHERE b.user_id = :user_id
GROUP BY  b.board_id,b.board_name,b.user_id
ORDER BY b.board_id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: Argh I copied and modified the OP's code, so the answer is 'the OP'. My bad for not checking his code more carefully. Fixed.

Comment: This didn't work by the way, I couldn't get past the syntax errors it was throwing. I've managed to work out a solution which i've posted as an answer.

Comment: @paulo77 - What are the syntax errors?  (I assume you replaced `:user_id`?)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this sql in your project.

```
SELECT customOffers.OfferNum, items.colour, items.availability
FROM 
(SELECT OfferNum
    FROM offers
ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 0 , 3) as customOffers
    JOIN items ON items.OfferNum = offers.OfferNum
```

Comment: What has this code got to do with the question?

Comment: He is going to get 20 rows from the main table. So, I just wanted to make him get a sense.